# What is this broken component?

Tags: identification

This is an IP Camera circuit and after i put accidentally 12vDC instead of 5vDC this component has died with smoking. I want to replace this component with new one but i didnt figurate it out what is this component and have a closer look under magnifier find some clues as u can see pictures below.
This component have 5 lead
Barely seen a write "A14P" maybe, but not sure
U10 sign left side of component.
Please help what is this component so i can order new one and replace it.

[image]

[image]

---

This is the full size circuit if it helps
[image]

Comment: Judging from the nearby inductor and capacitor, my bet is a switch regulator.

Comment: Look up the number on an SMT part database. I can see A14P, but your picture is terrible.

Comment: I think it says "AMP".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fried bugs in an SOT23-5 package with carmelized epoxy toxic fumes

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv62565.pdf

### p.s.

There is another SMPS , U20 which is likely for 3.3V USB and other logic chips.

Since this SMPS is located near the speaker port, I am having second thoughts about the function of this regulator. By tracing the output, you may find it is used as a boost regulator like +12V used for Speaker port amplifier (not visible) and the MOTOV1 port.   Shorting either of those outputs may have contributed to the problem of fusing the regulator. Although they tend to have UVP, OVP, OTP features that only works if the sense input is not damaged.  So handle with care and use a very low current limited lab supply in your experiments and gradually raise the current limit to 50mA with a preset voltage.

Comment: it's a SOT23-5 package!

Comment: How the hell could you figure this one out?

Comment: Proximity of circuit components and experience

Comment: I dont think it is. The device markings for a tlv64565 are SIK, SIL.

Comment: I agree it looks like that or equivalent. I'd be bypassing it and hooking up a power supply to see if the rest of the thing works before I went out and ordered anything though. I'd be very surprised if that is all that fried...

Comment: Even if it's not the TLV62565, by looking at the first picture, the pin-out of TLV62565 looks very reasonable. Still there are a lot of switching regulator with that pin-out...

Comment: Yeah, I saw the inductor, went "SOT23 switcher" but I was wondering if Tony kept the Handbook Of All Undecipherable Burnt SMD Codes under his pillow or something. But yeah, it'll probably work with an equivalent pinout chip. Unless the rest of the board is busted, which is likely, but... not our problem!

Comment: 1) The chip's got just over 5V of maximum input voltage. Could get fried by upstream over-voltage?  2) the output is possibly filtered by a modern high-capacity MLCC. These are not as immortal as ceramics are traditionally believed to be (by some). I'm also told that "tantals" can go "short and zap", especially after long periods of power-down. Good luck finding out what output voltage the chip should have, in the circuit (look for a resistive divider on the feedback pin). The chip also could've fried by pure long-term overheat. Does there seem to be enough copper around? (planned obsolescence

Comment: i want to inform against to misunderstands. I just accidentally give 12vDC instead of 5vDC and result is and the other hand if i do as u siad "Shorting either of those outputs may have contributed to the problem of fusing the regulator" work the device again ? without need new component ?

Comment: You put 12V into where?  and yes if it fried while doing this, that explains your learning experience on this. You must cut tracks and current limit the source to isolate it from 5V on USB. Did this card ever work? When did it fail? and why?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 how do you know it is TLV62565? There are 10's or even 100's of different SMPS in SOT23-5 package on the market. All with different specs.

Answer (score 3):

I see something worrying in your photo of the main PCB. If my hypothesis is correct then, unfortunately, you are wasting your time trying to replace the SOT23-5 `U10` component mentioned in your question.

In your photo of the main PCB, there seems to be a "blister" (i.e. a raised area) on the top of the main TQFP IC (`U16`?):

[image: Apparent "blister" on the top of TQFP IC (U16?)]

If that is really a "blister" on the IC, and not a reflection or other photographic anomaly, then the IC has probably suffered catastrophic internal damage. Damage to ICs like that, occurs due to internal heating.

My hypothesis is that when you connected 12 V to the 5 V power input, an excessive voltage was applied to other components including `U16`, causing internal damage. I *expect* that `U16` is a programmed MCU and so you will be unable to replace it, as it probably won't be sold, pre-programmed, as a spare part by the manufacturer of this IP camera. Also, other components on the PCB could also have been damaged by the over-voltage event.

That is why my conclusion is, if that IC is blistered, then you are likely to be wasting your time trying to repair that PCB.

Comment: You are right sir. Other components might be damaged :( how silly me a verry little moment of inattentiveness cost 50$

Comment: @BerkayGÜNDOĞU - Thanks for the reply. Can you please confirm that there definitely is a "blister" on top of that IC? Also, can you please give its part number?

Comment: yes sir its definetly blister on ic probably broken too i will send part number asap